# How to take a slice from a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list, where each item in the list is a list of 2 numbers:

```
myList = [[1,2], [4,3], [6,7]]
```

However, when I try to slice the list at an index I get an error. For example:

```
n = myList[1]
```

Returns:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

So, how to I store an index of this list in a new variable? My ultimate goal is to be able to access individual values from each list in the main list.

Comment: Your code is working perfectly. Screen your code and error.

Comment: Your posted lines neatly return `[4, 3]` for me.

Comment: Is there some missing code? `n` should equal `[4,3]`. how are you using n?

Comment: I suspect you're turning around and trying to use `n` as a slice, hence your error. (That is you can't then say `myList[n]` and expect it to work.)

Answer (score 0):

These tools might be helpful.

```
myList = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,0]]

# iterate through the list 
# prints the list in order 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
for subList in myList:
    for number in subList:
        print(number)

# index the list
myList[1] == [3,4]
myList[1][0] == 3

# slice the list
myList[1:4] == [[3,4], [5,6], [7,8]]
myList[1:]  == [[3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,0]]
myList[:4]  == [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]]
```